# Wordpress Changes Are Not Showing on My Website

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am experiencing problems with my website. I updated my web page, and it looks the same as before. My site is not showing the changes I uploaded.

I have tried many ways to fix this issue, but no help.

The following are some steps that I followed, but nothing worked for my website.

1. Force browser to reload or clear cache
2. Clear WordPress cache with the help of cache plugins
3. Clear cache from Hostinger hosting cache manager
4. Used different device/computer
5. Restart modem/router
6. Used a different device browser but no help.
7. Flushed my computer's DNS
8. Used Google Public DNS

What else do I need to do to resolve this problem? I have been experiencing this issue for 10 days now.

I would greatly appreciate help with advice on what to do to resolve this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you doing your updates? If you edit the fire on the server, are you seeing the updated version?

Comment: Frankly, I'd wonder if you're just editing the wrong file, perhaps even on the wrong server.

Comment: Are these updates to CSS or Php or… And are you using WPs built in edit methods or editing locally and ftping?

Comment: You need to confirm that you are uploading the files to the correct place. Change a backend aspect of the theme. For example in the theme css file update the name, description or something. Upload and see if you see the change. If you don't, then you need to figure out where the correct place is and what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the following ways
The first way:
If you use WordPress speed boosts such as Rocket, Total Cache, etc., disable them and do your updates again.
The second way:
Disable your site template and enable a default WordPress template and retest.
The third way:
Change your WordPress to a newer or older version and get tested.
The fourth way:
Disable WordPress plugins one by one and get tested at every step.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and your suggestions. I am going to try them all. I am sure that would be helpful on this.